# Se eu remover uma resposta com votos negativos eu recupero a reputação perdida?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Se eu respondo uma pergunta e recebo downvotes nela, nesse caso irei perder 2 pontos de reputação por downvote recebido. Caso eu apague a resposta, irei receber a reputação perdida de volta?

Mesmo caso para os upvotes, caso eu remova uma pergunta/resposta com uma quantidade de votos positivos eu perderei a reputação que ganhei naquele determinado post?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se você apaga uma pergunta ou resposta sua, os pontos que você ganhou ou perdeu são revertidos - basicamente, é como se aquela pergunta ou resposta não tivesse existido.

No [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/401803) é descrito esse funcionamento:

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified.

Em tradução livre:

> Alterações de reputação por recompensas, votos (tanto negativos quanto positivos) e respostas aceitas, relativas à posts apagados (incluindo respostas feitas à pergunta que for apagada) são anuladas.

O mesmo FAQ ainda cita algumas exceções:

- reputação obtida em posts com pontuação >= 3, na qual o post está visível no site por pelo menos 60 dias, [é mantida](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).
- se uma resposta que ganhou uma recompensa cai no critério acima e a respectiva pergunta é apagada, a reputação obtida pela recompensa não será revertida.
- se você perdeu reputação porque o seu post foi apagado por ser sinalizado como *spam* ou "rude/abusivo", esta não será revertida, a menos que um moderador cancele manualmente as sinalizações. Isso acontece apenas se o post foi apagado erroneamente (um moderador pode ter clicado no botão errado, ou vários usuários "conspiraram" para apagar o post).

Existem ainda outros detalhes (não diretamente ligados à reputação):

- a primeira vez que você apaga um post com pontuação >= 3, você ganha a medalha [Disciplinado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)
- a primeira vez que você apaga um post com pontuação <= -3, você ganha a medalha [Pressão dos Colegas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)
- se uma pergunta é apagada, todas as respostas existentes também são automaticamente apagadas. Se esta mesma pergunta é restaurada ("desapagada"), as respostas também são, exceto respostas que foram apagadas antes da pergunta.

Para mais detalhes sobre todas as regras envolvendo posts apagados, leia o [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/401803).

---

Vale lembrar também que se você apagar muitas perguntas ou respostas (e se muitas delas tiverem pontuações negativas), você pode acabar caindo nos [critérios de banimento](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/401803) e ser impedido de fazer novas perguntas ou respostas até que os posts problemáticos sejam arrumados.

Mas quanto é "muitas"? Não sei, os critérios não são divulgados para que as pessoas não tentem burlar o sistema.