# O que fazer com perguntas que não são mais consideradas boas para a comunidade?

Tags: debate, perguntas

No começo do site adotamos ao máximo a ideia de não criar regra para o que não era claro que tinha um problema. Isto permitiu muitas perguntas que não eram boas por várias razões, e aos poucos foi se verificando que elas eram de fato um problema.

No passado o SO em inglês passou por isso e perguntas que inicialmente foram aceitas acabaram sendo apagadas, bloqueadas ou fechadas.

Algumas perguntas ruins dão impressão que essas perguntas são aceitas e alguém pode fazer agora algo parecido. Algumas são tão ruins que as respostas mostram a inutilidade dela.

A pergunta aqui tem o intuito de saber o que fazer com uma específica que mostra problemas e o que fazer com as demais com problemas semelhantes ou outros.

A pergunta em questão é [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/101).

Veja como as respostas estão quase todas desatualizadas, tem repetições, tem pouca ou zero significância para outras pessoas, não respondem uma pergunta, é o que chamamos de lista de compras, que nunca foi bem aceito pela comunidade, ainda que a StackOverflow em determinado momento tentou forçar isto (tem comunidades que gostam disto, outras não).

A pergunta podemos:

- remover porque nada salva
- fechar para que não tenha novas respostas
- bloquear para que seja congelada como está em tudo, provavelmente por esse motivo:

[image: Significância história]

Ou até a combinação dos dois últimos motivos. Eu bloqueei temporariamente, e se não for removido eu acho que poderia fechar também.

Outra questão, se a pergunta não for removida, o que fazer com as respostas? Note que quase todas são ruins, tem *links* que não funcionam mais, e embora não tenha intenção de *spam*, a maioria é para serviços pagos, muitas vezes operados de forma irregular. Podemos apagar a maioria das respostas? Quais? Ou melhor apagar tudo?

**Então especificamente, o que fazer com a pergunta e suas respostas?**

## O que fazer no geral com perguntas que só existem por razões históricas?

Podemos fazer o mesmo que for decidido para a pergunta específica?

Quais as perguntas você listaria como ainda existente no site apenas por motivos históricos?

Eu sempre fui contra listas de compras como perguntas normais, mas acho que [elas podem caber no site de outra forma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7855/101).

Comment: Remover perguntas/respostas históricas, bem recebidas e bem votadas, iria consequentemente estornar a reputação do autor de cada uma. "**a maioria é para serviços pagos, muitas vezes operados de forma irregular.**" então poderiamos então estabelecer um princípio de "se for promover um serviço pago, promova um gratuíto também", e se os links não funcionarem, podemos comentar na publicação, solicitando links novos e atualizados, ou se você tiver algum, editar a pergunta/resposta.

Comment: A maioria das pessoas não são mais ativas na comunidade e nunca vão mexer ali.

Comment: Complementar: sugeri a tradução desse motivo de fechamento no [pt.traducir.win](https://pt.traducir.win/string/11272)

Comment: Eu sou a favor de remover. Não vejo nem significância histórica. 
Perguntas deste tipo acabaram passando por ser uma época que havia uma tolerância muito grande, a comunidade ainda estava tentando definir o escopo do site. Havia uma participação muito maior da comunidade focada no objetivo do site (proporção entre usuários no total e membros engajados com a proposta de criarmos um repositório "curado" de conhecimento). Creio que essa participação criava a ilusão de que sempre teriamos pessoas suficientes para organizar o site, mas hoje os mods tem que intervir muito mais do que seria ideal.

Comment: @Bacco tendo a concordar, a única coisa boa ali é mostrar como algo deste tipo pode ficar bem ruim. A intenção era boa, mas olha o que aconteceu, eu festival de informações inúteis e desatualizadas que ninguém mais cuida. Eu ach oque devemos fazer o mesmo que foi feito no SOen, ter um Cleanup Summer (no outro hemisfério :P, não lembro o nome que deram), no fundo objetivo é esse, mas quero opiniões.

Comment: Não removeria. Embora esteja muito bagunçado, acabou tornando-se uma referência para diferentes ideias, soluções e implementações. Inclusive foi por lá que descobri o projeto do CEP Aberto e que depois ele foi barrado pelos Correios. A princípio já poderia começar removendo as respostas que apontam para serviços que funcionam atualmente mas são irregulares.

Answer (score -1):

Se uma pergunta (e consequentemente suas respostas) não forem mais úteis, unilateralmente, seguindo as condições de:

- é ruim (uma pergunta boba, onde há respostas em qualquer outro lugar),
- é específica (trata-se de um problema de cenário único, não uma terminologia, situação abrangente ou geral),
- trata-se de tecnologias obsoltas, passadas, sem mais suporte,
- utiliza tecnologias que já não existem, bem como os links vinculados que apontam para o nada,
- não recebe mais visitas, "não ajuda mais ninguém",

A proposta é **arquivar**, para que não seja permanentemente excluída, mas não precisa mais ficar ali no site.

### Por que?

Como nas condições acima descritas, **ninguém irá precisar mais daquilo, e também não se importarão se ela sumir**. Talvez tenha ajudado no passado, mas hoje não faz mais sentido.

Nessa pergunta: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql) é citado por que parar de usar o prefixo nas funções de uma determinada tecnologia. Hoje, depois de 6 anos, ninguém mais vai usar este prefixo. O motivo é claro, foi **descontinuado**. Isso também é explicado na [wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) do PHP.

Ninguém vai perguntar isso nos próximos anos. Pelo menos, acredito que não.

No entanto, eu não preciso mais dessa pergunta. Se você não precisar também, podemos arquivar ela, para só "deixar de existir".

### Por que arquivar e não excluir?

Simplesmente para não revogar a pontuação dos autores na pergunta. Por mais que foi algo útil no passado, é injusto revogar o mérito de quem deu uma boa resposta (ou pergunta) naquele tempo.

Se quiserem excluir e então revogar, vamos então estabelecer uma data de validade para perguntas e respostas.

### Oportunidades para as mesmas perguntas, em tecnologias novas

Então começarão a aparecer as duplicatas do passado. Mas não vamos mais considerar duplicata, uma vez que ela foi arquivada. Mas também não vamos considerar uma pergunta totalmente nova se a comparação da nova pergunta e da histórica for muito similar (ou igual).

Deverá então estabelecer uma regra de considerar duplicata uma pergunta antiga (ou arquivada). A ideia é desconsiderar duplicata uma vez que a pergunta teve semelhança, mas a tecnologia mudou consideravelmente, a ponto da resposta da antiga não servir mais para a nova.

E então, reservar um cantinho no site para quem gostaria de ver as questões arquivadas. Lembrando que, ao arquivar uma pergunta, as respostas também serão arquivadas. E não poderiamos arquivar uma resposta e não sua pergunta, seria um fechamento e não um arquivo. E não é sobre isso que estamos tratando aqui neste debate.

Comment: A pontuação de coisas antigas não é removida se o *post* é removido, e não acho que a decisão deveria ser tomada por isso, afinal se a pergunta e resposta são ruins porque manter a reputação? De qualquer forma ela ficará. Vários usuários postam perguntas aqui sobre as funções obsoletas do MySQL, ela tem um conhecimento, não uma lista inútil de informações. Com relação a aceitar novas perguntas pra receber respostas atualizadas me parece errado porque é só começar o problema de novo.

Comment: Tem uns pontos legais, e numa leitura geral fica claro que o ideal é remover, mas infelizmente você dá um unico motivo para manter que eu discordo totalmente, por priorizar o pessoal em relação ao coletivo (lembrando que a presença do post, mesmo fechado, polui resultados de pesquisa e ainda pode atrapalhar a formulação de uma pergunta com assunto semelhante mas dentro do escopo). Sua resposta está muito bem elaborada, que fique claro que meu negativo é um voto de discordância da proposta apenas.

Comment: Tudo bem, eu vejo o **arquivar** seguindo o princípio do _quem sabe um dia vamos precisar_, em contra-argumento a tese do _é algo que não vamos mais precisar_.

Comment: @CypherPotato sim, fique tranquilo no sentido de que sua opinião e participação é valiosa, no meu caso é voto discordante mesmo, acho que vc se expressou muito bem. Aqui no meta vc sabe que negativo não necessariamente significa resposta errada, e o que o OP pediu foi isso, opinão das pessoas. Por mim eu daria "positivo pro post e negativo pra votação" se existisse o mecanismo. (até fiz questão de deixar o comment para registrar a razão do voto)

Comment: Apenas complementando, [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7681/112052) explica os casos em que a pontuação não é removida se o post for apagado. Creio que muitas dessas perguntas antigas caem no primeiro caso ("reputação obtida em posts com pontuação >= 3, na qual o post está visível no site por pelo menos 60 dias, é mantida")