# Perco reputação removendo uma resposta ruim dada por mim?

Tags: suporte, voto-contra, reputação

Respondi [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/559965/d%c3%bavida-sobre-rotas-usando-dois-tipos-de-aplica%c3%a7%c3%b5es/559967#559967) e recebei 2 downvotes nela, um tempo se passou e percebi que minha resposta realmente não estava de acordo com a questão então eu a removi e ao remover percebi que perdi 4 pontos de reputação, então restaurei e recuperei esses 4 pontos, por que ? Se a minha resposta estava com -2 e é uma resposta ruim faz sentido eu perder pontos removendo a resposta ? Não faria mais sentido eu ganhar os pontos dos downvotes de volta ?

Lendo a resposta [dessa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7680/297025) observei que o comportamento deveria ser diferente

Comment: A resposta tem 1 voto positivo (vc ganhou 10 pontos) e 3 negativos (vc perdeu 2 pontos pra cada voto), portanto no total vc ganhou 4 pontos com a resposta. Ao apagá-la, portanto, vc perde esses 4 pontos.

Comment: @hkotsubo como sei que a resposta tem 1 voto positivo ?

Comment: Abaixo das setas de voto tem um ícone de relógio, clicando nele e depois em "Mostrar resumos de voto", aparece isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/559967/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries - também dá pra ver no seu histórico, como respondido abaixo

Comment: Só como complemento: o mais importante aqui, se viu que a resposta está errada, foi a remoção. Ponto é parte do mecanismo de incentivo do site, mas muito sinceramente, preservar um erro por 4 pontos (ou 400 que fossem) seria uma inversão muito grande de propósito (entendo que tenha restaurado como teste). A sugestão é: foco no conteúdo e no objetivo do site, que o resto acontece (o que não invalida satisfazer a dúvida sobre o mecanismo, claro).

Comment: Concordo @Bacco, a ideia de restaurar a resposta era realmente entender o mecanismo, a resposta já foi removida.

Comment: @VictorBier Caso use Chrome, outra forma de ver o total de cada tipo de voto (sem precisar chegar nos 1000 pontos) é instalar [esta extensão](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O hkotsubo já explicou como está a pontuação e que no momento que ele comentou você perderia 4 pontos se apagar a resposta, mas pode receber um positivo e aí perderia 14, pode receber um negativo e aí só perderia 2. Ou seja, depende do momento.

Pode mudar editando a pergunta e a tornando boa, aí pode receber mais positivos, pode até reverter os negativos e fica tudo bem. Eu não li e não estou entrando no mérito da resposta dada, mas algo deve ter errado nela. Tem casos que a resposta é boa, mas não para a pergunta feita.

Você pode ver o resultado final mas não os votos individualmente diretamente na postagem. Mas pode ver [sua reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/297025/victor-bier?tab=reputation) para analisar melhor o que recebeu de positivos e negativos (pode ser difícil se for dado ao longo do tempo), ou pode ver o [histórico da postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/559967/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries). Poderá ver clicando no placar quando atingir [1000 pontos no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

[image: Ícone para clicar]

Comment: Faz mais sentido com a explicação de vocês, não havia pensado no voto positivo.